# Install package: magit (via package.el) only shows *Completions*

Tags: package

First time package user and magit user.

Following the installation instructions, when I enter "package-install magit", a *Completions* buffer is displayed, (see below).  I've tried adding both stable.melpa and melpa.  Neither give me the 'magit', by itself.

I'll be glad if someone can point out what this newbie is missing.  Should I see the 'magit' package by itself, or should I be selecting one from the *Completions* list?

```
Possible completions are:
magit-annex     magit-filenotify    magit-find-file     magit-gerrit
magit-gh-pulls  magit-gitflow   magit-imerge    magit-lfs
magit-p4    magit-rockstar  magit-stgit     magit-svn
magit-tbdiff    magit-topgit    magithub
```

Comment: My first theory is that it's *already* installed. Try `M-x magit-status`

Comment: Your theory was correct.  The instructions did not take that into account.  Unfortunately, it looks like magit won't work over TRAMP, so it's back to the shell prompt for my git commands.

Comment: Magit definitely *can* work over tramp (although it's generally much slower). If you're having difficulties with that, feel free to post a new question. I prefer to ssh into the remote machine and run emacs + magit on that machine in a terminal, as the performance is much better that way. If that's an option for you, you might want to try that.

Comment: You *might* have an old version of magit, mind. What does `M-x magit-version` tell you? v2.11.0 has just been released. If you're far behind that, maybe tramp isn't supported so well, and you could try updating.

Comment: Take note of https://magit.vc/manual/2.2/magit/Magit-claims-repository-accessed-using-Tramp-does-not-exist.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I will need a few days before I can get to try magit over Tramp.  I'll follow up separately, if I continue to have trouble with it.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37717/how-to-update-a-magit-install/41114#41114

Answer (score 2):

It was established in the comments above that this was happening because `magit` was *already* installed, and consequently was not a valid option for `package-install`.