# How to update a magit install

Tags: package

I am trying to update my Magit install.

The Magit manual has install instructions on
https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Installing-from-an-Elpa-Archive.html#Installing-from-an-Elpa-Archive

M-x package-install does not list "magit":

[image: minibuffer]

M-x magit-version says "2.11.0".

M-x list-packages lists "magit  2.12.1":
[image]

According to this post [Install package: magit (via package.el) only shows *Completions*](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/install-package-magit-via-package-el-only-shows-completions)
package-install is not a valid option if Magit is already installed.

How to update a Magit install?

I am running Spacemacs v.0.200.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I updated Magit on Spacemacs:

`M-x magit-version` says "2.11.0".

`M-x package-install` does not list "magit".

`M-x list-packages` lists "magit  2.12.1", mark it with 'i', then press 'x'.

`M-x list-packages`, click the "Package" header, lists "magit  2.11.0  obsolete":
[image]

`M-x magit-version` now says "2.12.1", but the old Magit still runs.

`M-x list-packages` press '~', then press 'x' to delete old packages.

Restart Spacemacs.

Now the new version of Magit runs.

From list-packages manual on https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Menu.html

```
i   Mark the package on the current line for installation (package-menu-mark-install).
    If the package status is ‘available’, this adds an ‘I’ character to the start of the line.
~   Mark all obsolete packages for deletion with ‘D’.
x   Download and install all packages marked with ‘I’, and delete all packages marked with ‘D’.
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't use `package.el`, so I had to look at [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html).

To update a package (any package) first show the list of packages. Most `package.el` commands are invoked from that buffer, `package-install` being a notable exception that can be easily be memorized and invoked without using that buffer.

In that buffer navigate the the packages line and press <kbd>u</kbd> to mark it as one of the packages that you want to be updated. Once you are done marking packages, carry out the actions by pressing <kbd>x</kbd>.

Instead of marking one package after another, you can also mark all packages that can be updated by pressing <kbd>U</kbd>.

Comment: "magit" is not listed by either M-x package-install nor M-x package-install, because magit is already installed.