# Why is the Magit M Remote pop-up different than what is shown in the Magit manual?

Tags: magit, install, manual

The Magit manual, 7.1.1 The Remote Popup, describes the following three commands, but they do not appear in my 'M' popup:

```
M C   (magit-remote-config-popup)
M p   (magit-remote-prune)
M P   (magit-remote-prune-refspecs)
```

What is the reason for the discrepancy?

List of commands from Magit manual on https://magit.vc/manual/magit/The-Remote-Popup.html#The-Remote-Popup:

```
M C
M a
M r
M u
M k
M p
M P
```

Screenshot from https://magit.vc/screenshots/ > M Remote:
[image]

At first I thought there was something wrong with my Magit installation.
But the above screenshot comes from official Magit documentation "A visual walk-through".
So now I wonder if the manual is wrong.

I am running Magit 2.12.1 on Spacemacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot and what you are seeing in your running Emacs are obsolete. You say you are using Magit 2.12.1 but that cannot be true. Maybe you have multiple versions of Magit installed and its an old one that actually gets loaded. Or you have outdated `*.elc` files laying around that get loaded instead of the up-to-date `*.el` files.

Use `M-x find-library magit RET` to located the version that actually gets loaded. Also try to uninstall and then reinstall Magit.

Comment: And if you use `package.el` to install packages, then add the `package` label to attract the attention of people who use that (I don't).

Comment: `M-x find-library RET magit RET` says "Copyright (C) 2008-2018  The Magit Project Contributors".  So I guess 2018 is the latest Magit version?  This is how I updated my magit version: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37717/how-to-update-a-magit-install .

Comment: The 'M' popup now has the expected commands for version 2.12.1 . Thanks for your help.   Here is how I fixed it: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37717/how-to-update-a-magit-install/41114#41114 .  Not sure if was the deleting obsolete Magit package or restarting Emacs that fixed it.